# Call rest api to push data to kinesis using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am a newbie in python and aws.I dont know much how to ask questions in stackoverflow.

Please do not block me.

I am trying to send a HTTP Post Request to put record into Amazon Kinesis Stream.

I have created a stream mystream in kinesis. I use method post.

I tried the following link to set up gateway api and it worked fine.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStream.html

I am trying to do it with python code using requests.

But i am getting the below mentioned error:

The following is my code:

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
import requests # pip install requests

# ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
method = 'POST'
service = 'kinesis'
host = 'kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
region = 'eu-west-1'
endpoint = 'https://kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'

content_type = 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
amz_target = 'Kinesis_20181114.PutRecord'
request_parameters = '{'
request_parameters += '"StreamName": mystream,'
request_parameters += '"Data":  + base64.b64encode(test) + ,'
request_parameters += '"PartitionKey": 1234 '
request_parameters += '}'


# Key derivation functions. See:
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4- 
examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python
def sign(key, msg):
return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key,datestamp,region,service):
kDate = sign(('AWS4' +key ).encode('utf-8'), datestamp)
kRegion = sign(kDate,region)
kService = sign(kRegion,service)
kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
return kSigning

# Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best 
practice is NOT
# to embed credentials in code.
with open ('C:\\Users\\Connectm\\Desktop\\acesskeyid.txt') as f:
       contents = f.read().split('\n')
       access_key = contents[0]
       secret_key = contents[1]


 if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
 print('No access key is available.')
 sys.exit()

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

canonical_uri = '/'

canonical_querystring = ''

canonical_headers = 'content-type:' + content_type + '\n' + 'host:' + host + 
'\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n' + 'x-amz-target:' + amz_target + '\n'

signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target'

payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(request_parameters).hexdigest()

canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + 
canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + 
'\n' + payload_hash

algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 
'aws4_request'
 string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + 
'\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()

signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

 signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), 
hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

 authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + 
credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 
'Signature=' + signature
print authorization_header;


headers = {'Content-Type':content_type,
       'X-Amz-Date':amzdate,
       'X-Amz-Target':amz_target,
       'Authorization':authorization_header}
 # ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
print '\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Request URL = ' + endpoint
r = requests.post(endpoint, data=request_parameters, headers=headers)
print '\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code
print r.text
```

The following error i am getting

AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAI5C357A6YSKQFXEA/20181114/eu-west- 
 1/kinesis/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz- 
 target, 
 Signature=1d7d463e77beaf86930806812188180db9cc7cff082663ad547f647a9c6d545a

BEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 Request URL = https://kinesis.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

RESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 Response code: 400

{"__type":"SerializationException"}

Please can someone explain me how i can rectify the above error?

Is the code connecting to the stream?Is there a problem regarding 
 serialization of data?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you're getting a `SerializationException` means your code is working to talk to kinesis but the data you're giving in `test` is likely not valid JSON.

That said:

I strongly recommend not doing the requests logic stuff yourself but use the software development kit (SDK) for AWS, called boto3.

```
import json

import boto3

kinesis = boto3.client("kinesis")

response = kinesis.put_record(
    StreamName="my-fancy-kinesis-stream",
    Data=json.dumps({
        'example': 'payload',
        'yay': 'data',
        'hello': 'world'
    }),
    PartitionKey="AdjustAsNeeded"
)
print response
```

This will instantiate a kinesis client using the credentials on your machine (either via instance metadata or ~/.aws/config) or environment variables.

Then it takes a simple dictionary and dumps it into a JSON string for the data.

Lots to say on partition keys that you can find out [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html).

Also, check out [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)!

Comment: Thank you for the help.I am following the following link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: Yup I saw - don't do that unless you really have to. That logic already exists in a library that Amazon maintains called boto3.

Comment: Actually i wanted to create a  call rest api for signature aws 4?

Comment: You don't want to see that. "I am trying to send a HTTP Post Request to put record into Amazon Kinesis Stream." <-- boto3 is the way to accomplish your stated goal it will do all of the signature stuff and request logic for you. I'd avoid dealing with the signature logic yourself because it is very easy to get it wrong.

Comment: ... I don't think postman can run python... I also don't think it could generate an AWS SigV4 signed request without some javascript pre-request code but that's a different question from what you're asking here. What is it that you're trying to do that you won't just use boto3 for?

Comment: The fact that you're getting a `SerializationException` means your code is working to talk to kinesis but the data you're giving in `test` is likely not valid JSON.

Comment: Please tell me how do i give a valid json?

Comment: I am giving now a valied json.Giving me same error({"a":"b"})..Serialization exception.Please suggest ..

Comment: I strongly suggest you use boto3. It will be very difficult to determine what is causing the serialization issues.